# How can I protect specific web pages from URL sharing? Temporary URLs?

Tags: browser, php, webserver, javascript, web

This is a technical question which is based on implementing a special feature on an website.
I know HTML and CSS, I know crude JavaScript (very basic) but I have no clue about PHP or other web-based script languages.

**What I want to archive:**
Someone goes to an URL and gets redirected to an temporal URL which will be accessible for this one person but cannot be shared to other People

**Why I want to archive this:**
I'm working on a website for a book. People who buy the book have access to Video Interviews on our Website. Video Interviews = Data we only want to be accessible for the people who bought the book.

We're using [Gatekeeper 2 <sub>(Javascript)</sub>](http://www.htmliseasy.com/keeper/index2.html) to protect this Interview-Page.
This means: If your password is *secret123* then our secret page is www.domain.com/secret123.html
The protection mechanism is very simple and seems to be effective.

The only problem is, that this 123abc.html page could easily be shared via social media, email or similar.

I'd like people who go to 123abc.html to be redirected to an temportarely existing page *(maybe IP locked?)* which make sharing the page useless.

**Example of expected behaviour:**
- I go to *www.domain.com/secret123.html*.
- I get redirected to *www.domain.com/3803bb9d4a884c188da7f4bfc7347385.html*.
- I'm able to enjoy the page without interference

Now this visitor shares the page with his friend. He copy and pastes the Link and some other guy clicks on it. The page redirects to the Password-Insert-Page (because the temporal site isn't accessible for him).
I know that this doesn't work if the password is shared instead of the link.

**My Question:**
How do I implement this on my website?
It doesn't need to be exactly as I described but maybe you guys know something that I could zse for this.

It should be fairly easy to write in PHP or Phyton but due to my lack of knowledge in these languages I cannot do it myself.

<sub>PS:

I hope I posted my answer at the correct spot. It's a technical question and thus is not related to [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)</sub>

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). 
Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), or flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: okay. I requested migration

Comment: Give up. The big publishing houses have not "solved" this. You have no chance.

Comment: Your comment doesn't add value. Also it's technically possible so there's no reason in giving up

Comment: @JonasDralle I've spoken to a mod from [so] and as it stands they believe your question may well get closed as being too broad. It would be good if you could narrow your question down to choosing one particular language and showing if you at least have the beginnings of some kind of solution. If you can edit your question to fit their guidelines as mentioned by David then that would be the best next step here.

Comment: Yea it's kinda broad I guess. I'll tinker on it

Comment: Well, any language that can serve up webpages can do it with a counter. Or by detecting the IP.  But you'd have to start off by asking how to write a hello world program in whatever server side language, that says "Hey, this is your IP".  Once you are at that stage Then you can look to consider questions like how to store that IP or use a counter.  I don't know those back end languages either but no doubt that's a route to your answer.